# Xamarin.Forms and ServiceStack exception - Couldn't bind to method 'CertStoreLookup'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, servicestack

We have a Xamarin.Forms android and ios app which has been performing well for a number of years now.  The latest version has been in prod since early 2017, and has had very few crashes. Until recently!

One of our android clients started getting exceptions when connecting to our ServiceStack powered API service.  Now our API service hasn't been changed since the App deployment (Jan 2017), and we've just started getting these errors in Dec 2017.

The details from the app logging on their device reveal the following.

```
Exception: The type initializer for 'System.AndroidPlatform' threw an exception.StackTrace: at System.Net.WebProxy.CreateDefaultProxy () [0x00000] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSystemWebProxy () [0x00000] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetDefaultProxy_UsingOldMonoCode () [0x00000] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection () [0x00015] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.WebRequest.get_InternalDefaultWebProxy () [0x00022] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor (System.Uri uri) [0x0008d] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebRequest:.ctor (System.Uri)
at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri, System.Boolean useUriBase) [0x00091] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.String requestUriString) [0x00014] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
at ServiceStack.PclExport.CreateWebRequest (System.String requestUri, System.Nullable`1[T] emulateHttpViaPost) [0x00000] in <0c56e395a4c44995b59b57d9e7ca7331>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.PrepareWebRequest (System.String httpMethod, System.String requestUri, System.Object request, System.Action`1[T] sendRequestAction) [0x0004e] in <d92dd3dd0cd44141a8ac071b8dc829af>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.SendRequest (System.String httpMethod, System.String requestUri, System.Object request) [0x00014] in <d92dd3dd0cd44141a8ac071b8dc829af>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse] (System.String httpMethod, System.String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, System.Object request) [0x00075] in <d92dd3dd0cd44141a8ac071b8dc829af>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Get[TResponse] (System.String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl) [0x00000] in <d92dd3dd0cd44141a8ac071b8dc829af>:0 
at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Get[TResponse] (ServiceStack.IReturn`1[T] requestDto) [0x00012] in <d92dd3dd0cd44141a8ac071b8dc829af>:0 
at [OUR APP].PCL.Services.Agent.IsAwake () [0x00013] in <cb1d96a8f02e4d9f92152b248e31ee23>:0 
Source: System
Has Inner Exceptions: True

Inner Exception 1: Couldn't bind to method 'CertStoreLookup'.
StackTrace: at System.Delegate.GetCandidateMethod (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bflags, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x000f9] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method, System.Boolean ignoreCase, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00014] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
at System.AndroidPlatform..cctor () [0x0002d] in <10a067eff09446018662189377d200e9>:0 
Source: mscorlib 
Has Inner Exceptions: False

25/01/18 11:01:19 IsAwake The type initializer for 'System.AndroidPlatform' threw an exception. Endpoint http://OURENDPOINT/
25/01/18 11:01:18 Sync Started
```

I have been able to reproduce this error, but only in a release build.  It all works fine in DEBUG mode, when using the Shared Runtime Framework.  So it's leading me to think that the release build packaging of Android is removing something that Android requires, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

### Version Info

```
VS2017 15.5.6
Xamarin 4.8.0.760
Xamarin.Android SDK  8.1.5.0
Xamarin.Forms v1.5.0.6447 (in PROD)
ServiceStack.Client (PCL proj via NuGet)  4.0.40 (in PROD)
Installed SDK's
8.0.0(26), 7.1.1(25), 7.0(24), 6.0(23), 5.01(21), 4.4.2(19),
```

### Build Config

```
Target Framework: 6.0 (v23)
Minimum SDK: 4.0.3 (v15)

**DEBUG**
Use Shared Runtime : true
Use Fast Deploy : false
Linking: SDK Assemblies only

**RELEASE**
Use Shared Runtime : false
Use Fast Deploy : false
Linking: none
```

I've been trying many things.. 
I've updated the Target Framework to 7.1 with minimum to 5.0, removed all Xamarin and ServiceStack references, and then installed the new ones that target the framework level.

Everything always works in DEBUG, but not in RELEASE.

Would greatly appreciate any assistance anyone could supply..

TIA.

### EDIT

After performing the steps suggested by @mahmoud-kamel, I get the following errors for the RELEASE build.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity::n_OnRequestPermissionsResult_IarrayLjava_lang_String_arrayI(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.Int32,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.App.Activity::OnRequestPermissionsResult(System.Int32,System.String[],Android.Content.PM.Permission[])
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() [OUR APP].DroidApp  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 1696    Build
```

Comment: Try upgrading Xamarin.Forms (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/). Sometimes it solves this kind of issues.

Comment: @KosalaW  I've done that in my efforts to get it working. Proj in VS is currently working with Xam.Forms v2.5.0.122203, and all Xam.Android.Support.* versions compatible with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a mismatch of assemblies referenced by the project.

After looking at the internals of the System.dll's in the bin/debug and bin/release folders, and comparing those of a new project from VS template, we were able to determine that after the project was upgraded to use the latest SDK, MSBuild wasn't retrieving the SYSTEM.dll from the correct ReferenceAssemblies folder location.

Doing a search for "ReferenceAssemblies" on my pc brings up about 4 locations!

The correct location (on my pc) is the following folder, with the Android version number folder (eg. "v8.0".

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\`

I hope this helps someone and saves them the hours I spent on this!

Answer (score 0):

put Target framework to the latest and the minimum is version 16

right click on Android project then go to options make sure that Release mode in linker tab and choose link SDK Assemblies only

save all changes then clean all solution , close the project and visual studio

go to folder of project then delete bin, obj folders

open visual studio , and try to start deploy project in release mode

Comment: Thanks for response.  However when I link with Assemblies I get a "The LinkAssemblies task has failed" error.. I've  updated the original question to show this.

Comment: i think this error related to differences between packages make sure 

you are using appropriate version for each one related to Xamarin.Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity package